# Quadratic irrationals with continued fraction of period one

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, quadratic-forms, continued-fractions

There are some quadratic irrationals (like $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5},\sqrt{10}$, etc.) that have continued fractions with a period of one (e.g. $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,\dots]$). I know the period of the fraction ends whenever $a_i=2a_0$, but is there any pattern to the quadratic irrationals that exhibit this behavior?

The Golden Ratio, for example, also famously has a period of one, with its continued fraction being $\phi = [1;1,1,1,1,\dots]$.

Comment: The mentioned rule for the end of the period only holds for $\sqrt{n}$. We can find out a form which a number must have if it has period $1$ , but I am not sure whether this gives an easy criterion allowing us to immediately decide whether a given surd has period $1$.

Comment: So, other than trial and error, there's no easy way to determine whether a given surd has period one?

Comment: I am not aware of such an easy way, but I am not sure whether there is one. The case $\sqrt{n}$ should have an easy criterion.

Comment: @Peter The one I mentioned?

Comment: I would have thought you want surds $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is $1$ or $4$ more than a square number. So $2,5,8,10,13,17,20,26,29,\ldots$ though $8$ and $20$ are really duplicates of $2$ and $5$

Comment: $\sqrt{13}$ has $[3,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,6,\cdots]$ , so the length is not $1$.

Comment: Same with $\sqrt{8}$ , which has $[2,1,4,1,4,1,4,1,4\cdots]$

Comment: The special case $\sqrt{n}$ has period length $1$ if and only if $n$ is of the form $k^2+1$

Answer (score 3):

In a first step, the case where no irregular part is present:

$$[0,n,n,n,\cdots]=\cfrac{1}{n+\cfrac{1}{n+\cfrac{1}{n+\cdots}}}=\color{red}{\frac12\left(-n+\sqrt{4+n^2}\right)}\tag{1}$$

Formula (1) comes naturaly from the fact that if we denote by $x$ the continued fraction in (1),

$$x:=\cfrac{1}{n+\cfrac{1}{n+\cfrac{1}{n+\cdots}}}$$

we find back in the right hand side $x$ in this (classical) way:

$$x=\cfrac{1}{n+x}$$

giving rise to a quadratic equation whose *positive* root is the left hand side of (1)

The case $n=1$ gives in particular $\Phi-1$. One needs to add $1$ to get Golden Ratio $\Phi$.

More generally, all continued fractions with hopefuly an irregular part can be obtained in this way by eventually "prefixing" by the beginning of a continued fraction. For example $$[a,b,c,n,n,n,\cdots]=\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{b+\cfrac{1}{c+\cfrac{1}{n+\frac12\left(-n+\sqrt{4+n^2}\right)}}}}$$

Examining this last form, one can see that, by successive multiplications par conjugate expressions, one can get an expression of the form indicated by richrow

Comment: How are $x$ and $n$ related?

Comment: But what about the cases like $[0,2,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,\cdots]$ ? Are they covered as well by this rule ?

Comment: $x$ account for the unknown continued fraction (its closed-form formula if you like).

Comment: But the object is to decide whether a given surd $$\frac{a+\sqrt{b}}{c}$$ has period $1$. How do we know whether it is of the form you mentioned ?

Comment: Let's call to real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equivalent if $\alpha=\frac{a\beta+b}{c\beta+d}$ for some integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $ad-bc=1$. As far as I remember, two real numbers are equivalent iff their continued fractions are the same after deleting some first terms (for example, $1+\varphi=[2,1,1,\ldots]$ is equivalent to $\frac{4\varphi+1}{3\varphi+1}=[1,3,1,1,\ldots]$). Thus, all real numbers which have continiued fractions with the period $1$ are equal $\frac{a\alpha_n+b}{c\alpha_n+d}$, where $\alpha_n=\frac{-n+\sqrt{n^2+4}}{2}$, $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $ad-bc=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ will have a (simple) continued fraction representation with a period of $1$ if and only if $(n-1)$ is a perfect square.  See chapter 4 of  [http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf) for details.

Note that $\sqrt{D} + a_1 = [\overline{(2\times a_1)}] = (2 \times a_1) \;+\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{D} + a_1} \;\Rightarrow$ 
$(\sqrt{D} - a_1)(\sqrt{D} + a_1) = 1.$